# JSLint message: "expecting expecting <\/ instead of <\ " -What is the reason(s) for that error?

Tags: jslint

I was using JSLint to validate my code and i received the following error:

"expecting </ instead of <\"

I got that for my HTML code and JavaScript code. For example:

```
element.innerHTML += "<p>here's what happened: You are <b>" + aVariable + " </b> years old.</p>";
```

and:

```
<input type="text" name="enterText" id="nameOfPerson" onblur="submitValues(this)" size="50"  value="Enter your name"/>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I think you mean Instead of `</`.

Answer (score 2):

In the [JSLint](http://www.JSLint.com/lint.html) section on HTML, it says:

> JSLint also checks for the occurrence of '</' in string literals. You should always 
>   write '</' instead. The extra backslash is ignored by the JavaScript compiler but 
>   not by the HTML parser. Tricks like this should not be necessary, and yet they are.

Comment: hmm i see. Is the extra backslash part and parcel of valid HTML code?

Comment: I think what's going on is multiple levels of escape characters.  When JSLint mentions the HTML parser, it's not the parser that will eventually interpret the &lt;/, it's the parser that is looking at "...&lt;\/...".  I think the point is to not confuse that parser into thinking that you've descended a level of HTML structure even though you were inside a quoted string at the time.  But that's a guess.  I only really know that Doug Crockford knows what he's talking about (and has talked to all the experts).  You should believe what JSLint says.